# Wordpress database - obtaining quantity of sales figures

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

Here is what I want to do. I am setting up a new commerce website for myself using WooCommerce. From each sale I will be donating $5 to a charity.  In the header of my Wordpress site I want to have a counter that shows how much money we have donated in this current week.

So how do I get the required number from the WP database? I guess I need to some how extract the number of sales from the database, multiply that by 5 and put it in the header.php with a $ infront of it.

I don't mind if I have to change code at the beginning of each week to reset the counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution store a value of number of sales, create a wordpress option and increment it in the process of making the sale.

Otherwise you need to look more into the db structure of your ecommerce code and perform a count query of all records between today - 7d and today.

Comment: Thanks Steve. So you mean somehow make a check box or something in the buying process, which is a required field?

Comment: I was thinking something more in the core and not a part of the UX.  The part of your code that validates a sale should increment the counter just before it returns true, or however it may be done.

Comment: Sounds way over my head. I've hired someone through Elance to work their magic for me, here's hoping he comes back with something nice for me.  Thanks! Adam